# Как в DataGrid отображать определенное количество строк? (C#/WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в DataGrid отображать определенное количество строк? Например только первые 15?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CsvGrid" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding csvTable}">


DataTable csvTable = new DataTable();
...
CsvGrid.ItemsSource = csvTable.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CsvGrid" ColumnWidth="*" LoadingRow="CsvGrid_LoadingRow" ItemsSource="{Binding csvTable}" />

private void CsvGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()+1).ToString();
    if(e.Row.GetIndex() > _showRows - 1) e.Row.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```